# Measurable subset of a product space has measurable sections

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(F, \mathcal{F})$ and $(G, \mathcal{G})$ be measurable spaces. How can we show
that if $E$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{G}$, then for every $x\in F$, the set $\{y\in G: (x, y)\in E\}$ is measurable in Y? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This holds for all measurable rectangles, so use Dynking/monotone class lemma to show that it holds for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by such rectangles. See e.g. Lemma 1.7.3 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.155.4899&rep=rep1&type=pdf).